# How ANTLR4 lexer consume more any tokens and stop at existing rules?

Tags: php, token, antlr4, lexer

Is ANTLR4 lexer can consume more any tokens and stop at existing rules?
Expect consume more chars into one token.

Small rules

```
lexer grammar PhpLexer;

options {
    superClass = PhpLexerBase;
    caseInsensitive = true;
}

T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO: '<?='  -> pushMode(PHP);
T_OPEN_TAG: PhpOpenTag -> pushMode(PHP);

T_INLINE_HTML: .+?;      // Problem Point

mode PHP;
   T_CLOSE_TAG: '?>';
   T_BAD_CHARACTER: .;

fragment NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' | '\r';

fragment PhpOpenTag
    : '<?php' ([ \t] | NEWLINE)
    | '<?php' EOF
    ;
```

Input:

```php
<html><?php echo "Hello, world!"; ?></html>
```

Got:

```
T_INLINE_HTML -> "<"
T_INLINE_HTML -> "h"
T_INLINE_HTML -> "t"
T_INLINE_HTML -> "m"
T_INLINE_HTML -> "l"
T_INLINE_HTML -> ">"
T_OPEN_TAG -> "<?php "
……
```

Expect:

```
T_INLINE_HTML -> "<html>"
T_OPEN_TAG -> "<?php "
……
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `T_INLINE_HTML: .+?;` result in the same as writing `T_INLINE_HTML: .;`: both will always match a single char.

Try something like this:

```
T_INLINE_HTML
 : T_INLINE_HTML_ATOM+
 ;

fragment T_INLINE_HTML_ATOM
 : ~'<'               // match a char other than '<'
 | '<' ~'?'           // match a '<' followed by something other than '?'
 | '<?' ~[p=]         // match '<?' followed by something other than '?' and '='
 | '<?p' ~'h'         // match '<?p' followed by something other than 'h'
 | '<?ph' ~'p'        // match '<?ph' followed by something other than 'p'
 | '<?php' ~[ \t\r\n] // match '<?php' followed by something other than a space char
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks  Bart. It works. By the way Is there a better solution when there are many rules? rather than inverting one by one

Comment: You're welcome. No, there is not: you'll need to do them one by one.